# Bad output taylor series sinx

Tags: math, output, taylor-series

i'm trying to write a program that gets from the user a value x and prints sinx using taylor series. but my output is bad. the output i get is not even a number, its -1.#IND00 regardless of what i input.

here's my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
void main()
{
    int i;
    double x,sum,last;
    sum=(double)0;
    scanf("%f",&x);
    last=x;
    sum=last;
    for(i=1;i<10;i++)
    {
        last*=(double)(-x*x)/((2*i)*(2*i+1));
        sum+=last;
    }
    printf("%f",sum);
    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see one problem:

```
scanf("%f",&x);
```

`x` is a double, so you need the `l`, i.e. `"%lf"`.

[true but irrelevant point about how this isn't the right formula for `sinh`, even though `sinh` is nowhere mentioned in the question, redacted..]

Comment: the question is about sin(x), not sinh(x), they do change signs. but thank you its working now :)